# Sqlalchemy session loading relationship for last added row even though 'noload' is set

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy model with a relationship which has noload set

```
class Servers(Base):
    __tablename__ = "servers"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    settings = relationship("Settings", uselist=False, lazy="noload")
```

I can create a object and add it to the table using `session.add(Servers(id=1, settings=Settings(<params>)))`
but when I query it using `session.execute(select(Servers).where(Servers.id == 1))`, the queried row gets serialized with the `settings` relationship loaded which is accessable using `object.settings`, oddly enough, this only happens when the added object/row is the last one added.

Comment: This only happens for me when the settings instance has not yet been committed, which would make sense to me.  If the `settings` attribute was set to `None` then it would be overwritten at commit time.

Comment: @snakecharmerb are you committing using `session.commit()` ? because i am committing after i add the instance, its also worth noting I'm using the asyncio sqlalchemy API, would you mind sending me your test code so I can play around with it and test what I'm missing?

Comment: `server = Servers(settings=Settings())`; `session.add(server)`; `<run query & print results>`.  If I commit before querying the `settings` attribute is `None`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb This seems to be a sqlalchemy asyncio specific issue, I have tried committing in nhe synchronous API and it seems to working normally...

Comment: Solved - expire_on_commit was True